# How to Execute Batch apex class from controller

Tags: schedulebatch

I am Executing Batch apex class from normal controller
It is executing Start Method but it is not going to Execute method 
Can you please help me on this

```
     SampleChargeBatch1  chargeBatch =new SampleChargeBatch1();
     ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(chargeBatch);
```

Comment: The code you have posted looks normal enough. Have you checked to see if anything useful (errors or batches waiting to be processed) is reported in Setup -> Jobs -> Apex Jobs? Another possibility is that your initial query is returning no records. If that is the case and you can't see why post the SampleChargeBatch1 source code.

Answer (score 2):

I would typically set up a batchable context like the code below.

Execute via a schedule like: `OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob.scheduleMe();`

To execute from a controller I would do the following:

```
OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob  batchJob = new OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob();
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
```

// ....
    // ....

```
global with sharing class OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob implements System.Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful
    {

        // Schedule String
        public static String sched = '0 00 00 * * ?';  //Every Day at Midnight

        // Method to execute schedule
        global static String scheduleMe() 
        {
            OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob Job = new OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob(); 
            return System.schedule('Refresh OLIs for Roll Up Summary Fields', sched, Job);
        }

        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            // Start the job once the scheduled time has arrived
            Database.executeBatch(new OpportunityLineItemsRefreshJob());        
        }

        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
        {
            // Obtain appoprite query locator from the selector
            return new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().queryLocatorReadyToMassUpdate();  
        }

        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<OpportunityLineItem> olis)
        {
            try
            {
                // OpportunityLineItems ready to Update
                Set<Id> olisToUpdate = new Map<Id, SObject>(olis).keySet();

                new OpportunityLineItemService().updateOLIMassUpdate(olisToUpdate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Catch
            }
        }

        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
        {

        }

    }
```